# Split XML line in bash ignoring spaces in quotes

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split, text-manipulation

I've seen some suggestions to use eval, but that assumes the quoted text is an entire string in itself, and not part of one.

Simple example:

Split the string

```
<SERVICETYPE Name="Two words">
```

So that we get

```
<SERVICETYPE
Name="Two words">
```

Is this possible? Ideally in a statement that I can then use to loop through the values. (Yes, I know perl or something would be easier, but I don't have anything more useful than bash availale, so I have to get this working).

I'm currently splitting into an array with the following

```
IFS=" " read -ra xmlfield <<< ${xmlline}
for i in "${xmlfield[@]}"; do
```

But then of course that gives me:

```
<SERVICETYPE
Name="Two 
words">
```

Which is a pain.

Comment: what is the real benefit of split an xml tag? I see no benefits. ... homework?

Comment: Is sed available?

Comment: This sounds like an XY question for "how do I get values from an XML document", for which the answer is to use a cli xml parser like `xmlstarlet`, `xpath` or `xidel`.

Comment: @thatotherguy Unfortunately there is no cli xml parser installed, nor do I have the possibility to get one installed. I wish I did.

Comment: @amasmiller Yes

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It's for feeding into another system, where I haven't set , or had any say in, the format requirements.